# double click to change tree label

Tags: javascript, html, tree

I have a javascript tree control that I have constructed with nested UL and LI's.  I want to enable users to double click to change the label of an item in the tree.  I put this line at the top:

```
<ul id="dhtmlgoodies_tree2" class="dhtmlgoodies_tree" ondblclick="change(event)">
```

and for the change function I have:

```
function change(ev) {

ev.preventDefault();
console.log(ev)
var it = prompt("Channel Name", "");
}
```

When I look at the value of ev, it is everything about the mouse click event (location, etc.).  Is there some way I can get the handle to the tree and even better the LI on which they clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ev` also has a `target` property which is exactly the element user clicked on.

So, for example, adding `ev.target.textContent = it;` to your function will change the element text to user's answer.

Comment: OK, so then I can get the element by looking at ev.target.parentElement.  The worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do it with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) like this:

```
$("ul li").ondblclick(function(){
   var text = $(this).text()
   console.log(text)
});
```

Hope it helped you.